# Как статический метод сравнивает

Tags: javascript

```js
class Article {
  constructor( title, data){
    this.title = title;
    this.data = data;
  }
  static compare(ArticleA, AtricleB){
    return ArticleA.data - AtricleB.data;
  }
}


let articles = [
  new Article("HTML", new Date(2019, 1, 1)),
  new Article("CSS", new Date(2019, 0, 1)),
  new Article("JavaScript", new Date(2019, 11, 1))
];


articles.sort( Article.compare );

console.log( articles[0].title )
```

1. метод constructor создает объект свойствами title и data
2. создается статический метод который прикрепляется классу Article
3. В массиве articles  создаются объекты свойствами title и data
4. код сортирует articles.sort( Article.compare );
5. Вопрос как статический метод compare получает доступ к объектам которые создаются в массиве ?

Comment: Из передаёт функция sort первым и вторым аргументом.

Comment: Статический это метод или нет совершенно неважно. Это может быть вообще отдельная функция